# How can I organize my code to optionally provide a backing view for my logic layer?

Tags: ios, architecture, custom-component

*I'm a bit sceptic wether this belongs to stackoverflow or not, please let me know if I should post to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead.*

I want to write a reusable component for iOS that does something like this:

1. Accepts a number as an input, let's call it `inputNumber`
2. Records audio for 10 seconds or until the user stops recording
3. During recording shows live metering
4. After the recording, checks the recording using the provided `inputNumber` (we don't really care about this part at the moment)
5. Allows the user to play the recorded audio
6. Returns a path to the recorded file
7. Returns `YES` or `NO` based on the check of step 4

The GUI is pretty simple, just two buttons (play/pause and record/stop) together with a view for showing the audio metering during recording.
Something like this:

[image]

Now, I have implemented all the logic I need in a singleton "manager" class and what I want to do is also provide the GUI. That means that the consumers will not care about enabling/disabling buttons, showing/hiding the meter etc.

I would like for others to be able to keep using this "manager" (and probably it will be refactored to stop being a singleton), but at the same time I would like to give the option to use it as a "drop in" view.

So, this is a question of how can I setup the whole architecture.

Right now my manager has only one method:

```
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(BOOL isValid, NSString* filePath, NSError *error);

-(void)evaluateRecordingForInputNumber:(NSNumber *)inputNumber completion:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```

and this works as I want.

But if I introduce a view, how should my API look? It doesn't seem correct to me to write a custom UIView `-init` that will take the role of the aforementioned method, since ideally I would like to reuse this view for different model classes (providing the `inputNumber`) that need to be evaluated.

How can I choose between subclassing `NSObject`, `UIControl` or `UIView` in my case? Is there a nice way to use both my "engine" as a standalone component and also optionally provide a backing view layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this coupling is largely dependent on how you envision the custom view/manager being used.

Will it be a lot of logic that people can use without the view, and the view is just an optional feature? If so it likely makes sense to subclass NSObject and prove the view as a property of the manager itself. That way people can use your manager class as a standalone, and in UIView's where it's needed they can do something like the following:

```
[self.view addSubview:myCustomManager.audioView];
```

On the other hand if the manager class has no value to your user without the UIView itself then I think it makes a lot of sense to subclass UIView, and hide your manager class behind that UIView. One example of a widget that uses this style of implementation is stripe: [Stripe iOS Widget](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios). Everything is based off of their 'STPView', like retrieving a charge token:

```
[self.stripeView createToken:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
        // [self handleError:error];
    } else {
        // Send off token to your server
        // [self handleToken:token];
    }
}];}
```

One can imagine a private 'manager' class behind the scenes of the stripeView doing all the work (this method is in addition to their delegate callback).

In your case this might be a fairly good pattern. You can add a property to the custom view for the number to be evaluated, add the view to the hierarchy, and then create a custom delegate that calls back automatically after it processes things; which would take the place of your manager class callback.

The final answer is that it depends a lot on how much of split between business logic and UIView treats this will provide. As long as the code is readable, maintainable, and you have some reasonable pattern to follow I don't think anyone is going to nail you to a cross in iOS land.

Comment: That's a good answer, thanks. I implemented your first suggestion and I also found out that `MPMoviePlayerController` is a good example of what I was trying to achieve.